# Association is not working in extjs4 when I am uploading my application to server?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, associations, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I am working in extjs4 MVC. I am getting stuck at a point where I have been working on association.Association is working properly when I am using in my system local side.But when I am uploading it to server side then the associated data is not displaying.I am trying a lot but not getting answer how this conflict occurs.
My application is working properly at client side.It displays associated data also.But when when I uploading data to server side then it does not display associated data.

Here is my application's some part which is working at local side:--

[image: Working at local side]

But when I am  uploading my side to server side then the options means associated data is not displayed
[image]

Here Is my some code:--

1) Model class :--

```
  Ext.define('B.model.kp.PollModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idproperty:'',//fields property first position pk.
    fields: ['pollId','pollQuestion','isActive','pollTypeId','createDate','userId','publishDate','isPublished','approvalUserId','percentagevotes','optionId'],
    hasMany:{
        model:'B.model.kp.PolloptionModel',
        foreignKey:'pollId',
        name:'options',
    },
    proxy:
    {
        type:'ajax',
        api:
        {
            read:'index.php/KnowledgePortal/Poll/GetPublicPoll',
            create:'index.php/KnowledgePortal/Pollvote/setPollVote',
        },//End of api 
        reader:
        {
            type:'json',
            root: 'polls',
            //successProperty: ,
        },//End of reader
        writer:
        {
            type:'json',
            root: 'records',
            //successProperty: ,
        },
    }//End of proxy
});
```

2) Store class :--

```
Ext.define('B.store.kp.PollStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'B.model.kp.PollModel',
    autoLoad: true,
});//End of store
```

3) View class:--

```
Ext.define('B.view.kp.poll.PollView',{
    extend:'Ext.view.View',
    id:'pollViewId',
    alias:'widget.PollView',
    store:'kp.PollStore',
    config:
    {
        tpl:'<tpl for=".">'+
        '<div id="main">'+
        '</br>'+
        '<b>Question :-</b> {pollQuestion}</br>'+
        '<tpl for="options">'+     
            '<p>{#}.<input type="radio" name="{parent.pollId}" value="{optionId}">&nbsp{option}</p>'+
        '</tpl></p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</tpl>',
        itemSelector:'div.main',    
    },
});// End of login class
```

4) here is my main view class

```
Ext.define('B.view.kp.poll.Poll',{
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    requires:[
              'B.view.kp.poll.PollView'
              ],
              id:'pollId',
              alias:'widget.Poll',
              title:'Poll',
              //height:180,
              items:[
                     {
                         xtype:'PollView',
                     },
                     ],//end of items square
                     buttons:[
                              {
                                  disabled:true,
                                  name:'vote',
                                  formBind:true,
                                  text:'vote',
                                  action:'voteAction'
                              },
                              {
                                  text:'result',
                                  action:'resultAction',      
                              }
                              ]
});
```

5) And here is the json file --

```
{   
    'polls': [
        {
            "pollId": 1,
            "pollQuestion": 'Who will win the match',
            "options": [
                {

                    "optionId":1,
                    "option":'India',
                    "pollId":1
                },
                {

                    "optionId": 2,
                    "option": 'Pakistan',
                    "pollId":1
                },
                {

                    "optionId": 3,
                    "option": 'Srilanka',
                    "pollId":1
                },
                {
                    "optionId": 4,
                    "option": 'Australia',
                    "pollId":1
                },
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

6) PollOption model class :--

```
Ext.define('B.model.kp.PolloptionModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    //idproperty:'',//fields property first position pk.
    fields: ['optionId','option','pollId','percentagevotes'],
    associations:[
    {type:'HasMany',    model:'Pollvotemodel',  foreignKey:'optionId'},
    {type:'BelongsTo',  model:'PollModel',  foreignKey:'pollId'},
    ]
});
```

Please someone give me some suggestion to solve this problem...

Answer (score 0):

are you sure your server-side data feed is *exactly* the same as your local data feed.

Are the related questions entered into the live database?

Comment: I got the solution for it.By mistake i was not included associated model class in controller file thats why this problem occurs...But still I have confusion that how it works at local side without including associated model in controller class...